# Facebook Ads Insights API: action_type, device & country breakdown not possible

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights

I am using Facebook Ads Insights API to get information about how many clicks an ad had and how much has been spent. I want to breakdown this to action_type, device and country to get something like:

```
ad_id: 123, device: iPhone, country: de, clicks: 30
ad_id: 123, device: iPhone, country: at, clicks: 20
ad_id: 123, device: iPad, country: de, clicks: 7
ad_id: 123, device: iPad, country: at, clicks: 3
```

But when having action_type, country, impression_device as a breakdown combination I get the error:

> message: (#100) Current combination of data breakdown columns
>   (action_type, country, impression_device) is invalid

So I can either get (action_type, country) or (action_type, impression_device), but we want the combo of all three. Does anyone know if there is a different way to get a report according to our needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to storage restrictions, only some permutations of breakdowns are available.

[Combine breakdowns](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/breakdowns/#combiningbreakdowns)

Comment: And yet, in Facebook Business Manager reporting, you can do breakdowns not supported in the API. These "storage restrictions" sound like BS.